# Data type mismatch in criteria expression in dataadapter.Fill(ds)

Tags: ms-access-2007, c#-3.0

Actually im creating report in c#, having to Datetimepicker,Button and datagridview when im selecting a date and click on show report its give me error in dataadapter.Fill(ds); line
    im using access database for this here im giving my table structure

```
AccountNumber--Number
Account-- Memo
Date--Date/Time
Description--Memo
Post_Ref--Memo
Debit--Number
Credit--Number
Balance--Number


private void btnshowreport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
 string connetionString = null;
            DateTime startT = new DateTime();
            DateTime endT = new DateTime();
            startT = dateTimePicker1.Value.Date;
            endT = dateTimePicker2.Value.Date;
            connetionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["AccessConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
            cnn.ConnectionString = connetionString;
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Billing where [Date] Between'"+startT+"'And '"+endT+"'";
            OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(connetionString);
            OleDbDataAdapter dataadapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(sql, connection);
            DataTable ds = new DataTable();
            connection.Open();
            dataadapter.Fill(ds);
            connection.Close();
            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
            show_data();
}
```

Comment: I suggest you to learn & use 'parameterized query' instead of using pure string like you did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the proper format for the date expressions:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Billing where [Date] Between #" + startT.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "# And #" + endT.ToString("yyyy'/'MM'/'dd") + "#";
```

Comment: thank you very very very much bro problem solve last two days im trying thanx bro